# mysql trigger on update, keep column higher than other

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a mySql trigger.

Table program_user looks like this :

user_id | program_id | week | max_week | is_active |

My goal is to maintain the integer from `max_week` always equal or higher than `week`
Because the `week` can be reseted by the user, I need to keep his best progression.

The rows are already created and are updated in 3 different ways:

- by the server (+1 to actual week)
- reseted by the user (`week` =1)
- setted by the admin

I tried multiple codes in with after update, to update the row itself, but none of them seems to work. Google seems not find any similar case, nor stackOverflow :(

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE `program_user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prog_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `week` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_week` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `program_user` (`user_id`, `prog_id`, `week`, `max_week`, `active`) VALUES
(6967, 1, 2, 2, 1),
(6967, 2, 2, 4, 0),
(6967, 3, 1, 1, 0),
(6967, 4, 1, 1, 0),
(6967, 5, 1, 1, 0),
(6968, 1, 1, 1, 1),
(6968, 2, 1, 1, 0),
(6968, 3, 1, 1, 0),
(6968, 4, 1, 1, 0),
(6968, 5, 1, 1, 0);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trigg_max_week1` BEFORE UPDATE ON `program_user` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       IF new.week >= old.max_week THEN
          SET new.max_week = new.week;
       END IF;
    END
$$
DELIMITER ;

ALTER TABLE `program_user`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `user_idpk` (`user_id`,`prog_id`);


COMMIT;
```

then updating :

```
UPDATE `program_user` SET `week` = '5' WHERE `program_user`.`user_id` = 6967 AND `program_user`.`prog_id` = 2;
```

result : no error when saving the trigger, nor while updating any week column, however, the column max_week stays to its initial state after update.

Thank you :)

Comment: Looks like it should work, do you have examples which don't?

Comment: no error when saving the trigger, nor while updating any week column, however, the column max_week stays to its initial state

Comment: Works fine for me do you have examples which don't?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) as SQL is a declarative language.. Where you define what you want and not how you you want it have it meaning table structures/constraints or data for that matter can change the execution/meaning of a SQL statement..

Comment: The only thing I could note that you need a trigger on before insert as well if you want to cover the record creation.

Comment: I edited my post so you can have a concrete reproductible exemple, thanks for feedback :)

Comment: Your sample data works fine.

Comment: Same here. It's working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see your problem, your trigger works as expected with the information provided..

```
drop table if exists program_user;
CREATE TABLE `program_user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prog_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `week` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_week` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `program_user` (`user_id`, `prog_id`, `week`, `max_week`, `active`) VALUES
(6967, 1, 2, 2, 1),
(6967, 2, 2, 4, 0),
(6967, 3, 1, 1, 0),
(6967, 4, 1, 1, 0),
(6967, 5, 1, 1, 0),
(6968, 1, 1, 1, 1),
(6968, 2, 1, 1, 0),
(6968, 3, 1, 1, 0),
(6968, 4, 1, 1, 0),
(6968, 5, 1, 1, 0);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trigg_max_week1` BEFORE UPDATE ON `program_user` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
       IF new.week >= old.max_week THEN
          SET new.max_week = new.week;
       END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

ALTER TABLE `program_user`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `user_idpk` (`user_id`,`prog_id`),
  ADD KEY `const_seance_id_seance` (`prog_id`);


UPDATE `program_user` 
    SET `week` = '5' 
WHERE `program_user`.`user_id` = 6967 AND `program_user`.`prog_id` = 2;

select * from program_user WHERE `program_user`.`user_id` = 6967 AND `program_user`.`prog_id` = 2;

+---------+---------+------+----------+--------+
| user_id | prog_id | week | max_week | active |
+---------+---------+------+----------+--------+
|    6967 |       2 |    5 |        5 |      0 |
+---------+---------+------+----------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thanks for help, i restarted the server services and things look working now... I don't know what happened there, works fine now too... Just lost my time and yours here :/